# Providing download links in php

Tags: php, video, upload, download

I recently uploaded videos,audios and pdf files using php to my multimedia folder on my server.

Basically its a site providing tutorials on various engineering subjects. I have kept folders like mechanics, computer programming etc and stored files in them accordingly, now i want to provide a link to the files using hyperlinks so that user can view them.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking how to make links, how to make links to specific resources, or how to make those resources accessible from a remote client?

Comment: see i want hyperlinks to access them from my server.....like http://example.com/abcd.flv....

Answer (score 4):

To show files to user use this.

```
$dir    = '/mechanics';
$files = scandir($dir);
```

You will get the **files** array. And you can acces them as files[0], files[1 ].

Now if you want to give them facility to download then use this.

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('huge_document.pdf');
?>
```

For more detail see [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm)

Comment: hey i liked ur idea...but i have different types of files like flv, pdf etc and if my array has 5 files of different format....how to print the link of all the files...as in do i have to print second code of urs in a loop!!

Comment: and for different format pass the argument as a file type to the downloading page

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to enable directory listing, by putting `Options +Indexes` in an .htaccess file. This way, all files in that directory will be shown by your web server as a listing.

You could also look at [dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php) or [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

Comment: While that may work, it's possibly the most insecure thing you can do... Directory listings should only be enabled on highly trusted systems like a corporate intranet, unless you don't care at all who sees them (and don't want to track who downloads them).

Comment: OP did not post any restrictions on that. I don't want to put more effort in my answer than OP put in his question.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/scandir

with this function you can scan all files and directories in a folder. with the return value you can generate in a for-loop hyperlinks

Answer (score 2):

Well, I believe there are two approaches.

One is create a loop for respected directories:

```
<? php
$yourDirectory = "../path/to/your/directory/";
if (is_dir($yourDirectory )) {
    if ($reading = opendir($yourDirectory)){
        while (($files = readdir($reading)) !== false){
            if( $files != "." && $files != ".." && $files[0] != "." ){
               echo "<a href='fancybox'><img src='$files' alt='' /></a>";
            }
        }
        closedir($reading);
    }
}
?>
```

by this way you can view your videos in Fancybox. Of course you need to set Fancybox plugin first.

Other way is using FlowPlayer to play content in your pages.

Hope this helps.